# Google Apps Script to move cursor to last edit location is now failing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I've got some code that I've been using just fine for months and it suddenly fails. The code makes the google sheet go to the last edited cell upon opening.

```
function onEdit(e) {

var ss = e.source
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
var row = cell.getRow();
var column = cell.getColumn();
var sheet_name = sheet.getSheetName();
var scriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

scriptProperties.setProperty('row',row);
scriptProperties.setProperty('column',column);
scriptProperties.setProperty('sheet name',sheet_name);
}

function onOpen(e) {

var properties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

var ss = e.source;
var sheet_name = properties.getProperty('sheet name');
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet_name);
var row = properties.getProperty('row');
var column = properties.getProperty('column');
var cell = sheet.getRange(row,column);

ss.setActiveSheet(sheet);
ss.setActiveRange(cell);
}
```

When I look at the Failed Execution log I see this:

> Feb 29, 2020, 7:43:12 AM   Error   Exception: Cannot convert '10.0' to int.
>       at onOpen(Code:26:18)

Has something changed on Google's back end that invalidates my code?

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**

Passing `String` type to a method that expects `Number` as an argument.

**Explanation**

The error message is pretty self-explanatory: a `String` "10.0" cannot be converted to an `Integer`. Have you by any chance migrated to the new V8 runtime? The issue is easily confirmed there, this sample will result in the exact same error:

```
function testStringToIntError() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('spreadsheet id');
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('4');

  const store = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();

  const propName = 'testStrToInt';

  store.setProperty(propName, '10.0');

  const res = store.getProperty(propName);

  sh.getRange(res,1);

  Logger.log(res);
}
```

**Solution**

I would suggest making sure that `row` is of type `Number` by explicitly converting it with `+` or `parseInt()`, and that will work just fine.

**Notes**

1. Not sure why it worked for you before. **UPD**: indeed, after retesting the sample in Rhino, the runtime does allow type mismatch, so that's why the script worked before, but stopped now.
2. `PropertiesService` stores data as `String`s, so you should always prepare it correctly when you use `setProperty()` or `getProperty()` (e.g. `JSON.stringify()` -> `JSON.parse()` for objects, etc).

**Reference**

1. `getRange()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column)
2. `Properties` [guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#data_format) (anchored to data format section)